# Test Rutas de ficheros en Angular2

Tags: angular

Quiero hacer una comprobación en Angular2 que consiste en verificar que dicho archivo está ahí y que no ha sido borrado de forma accidental.

El problema es que me doy cuenta que estoy comparando las cadenas no el fichero en si.

```
it('I check routes i18n', () => {
const  i18nEs = "../../../server/i18n/es.json";
const i18nIng = "../../../server/i18n/en.json"

expect(i18nEs).toBe("../../../server/i18n/es.json");
expect(i18nIng).toBe("../../../server/i18n/en.json");

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes prepararte un servicio que haga una petición HEAD a tu recurso local:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

getFileStatus(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.http.head(path)
        .mapTo(true)
        .catch((error) => Observable.of(false))
        .toPromise();
}
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543819/angular2-check-file-existance-with-http-get)